# Word macro referencing Excel worked in Office 2007 but fails in 2010

Tags: libraries, microsoft-excel, dll, vba, microsoft-word

I created a VBA macro in Word 2007 that determines if Excel and a specific Excel workbook is open, opens the workbook (and Excel if needed), then performs various tasks in the workbook.

Under Tools/References, I checked Microsoft Word 12.0 Object Library, Microsoft Office 12.0 Object Library, and Microsoft Excel 12.0 Object Library. The macros ran just fine. I then recently moved to a new PC and Office 2010 and neither of the commands below produces results - appExcel continues to be Nothing.

```
Set appExcel = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
```

I have searched high and low for specific info on how to remedy this, but to no avail. I've found various info that points to either both the 2007 and 2010 dlls being registered, or the one that is necessary not being registered, but nowhere can I find instructions on how to register or unregister either. Nor can I find clearly the file names involved. I'm hoping someone in Stack Exchange can help!

Comment: this is an outright off-topic, totally ignoring what Programmers is **[about](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/tour)**: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim excelapp As Object
Set excelapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
```

Is what you're looking for. If you don't see it then use `excelapp.visible = true`.

Answer (score 1):

While [the fix recommended by Raystafarian](https://superuser.com/questions/944450/word-macro-referencing-excel-worked-in-office-2007-but-fails-in-2010#answer-944454) helped, the full solution included removing the following registry key:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\TypeLib{00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\1.8

I'm now a very happy camper.

Answer (score 0):

Fix the API references as follows:

1. In Excel press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to go to the coding window
2. Open the **Tools** menu and choose **References**
3. Uncheck the `Missing:` item in the list
4. Scroll down and add a reference to the new version of Microsoft Word.